# How to bundle asset for angular application that is loaded elsewhere

Tags: angular

For an Angular 7 application that finally build to

```
- main.js
- assets
  -- assets/img
```

With an component/html that reference to asset as

```
src='./assets/img/img1.jpeg'
```

The application would be given to different teams and can be hosted on different roots

```
example.com/route/first
example2.com/route/second
```

If the consumer refer to my build content as
`<script src=''../some-dir/libs/main.js">`

The Angular application will look at the current path to find assets (  example.com/route/first/assets ) which will force them to copy-paste the asset folder that I provided to their root. *I imagine It would be much more simple for the customer if my component can look for my asset at the location relative to my build content ( `'../some-dir/libs/asset'` ), instead of their directory root. However I'm not very sure if what I expect is industry standard or appropriate*

How can I correctly build/bundle/reference assets that the consumer can use anywhere by just extracting and referencing/importing my build content ?
( That I don't need to know consumer's project structure and the consumer does not need to alter my/his folder structure )

Answer (score 5):

**Just use relative url in app** like this:

```
<img src='./assets/img/img1.jpeg' />
```

**If you know where the root context is**, build your app with `base-href` and `deploy-url` parameter like this:

```
ng build --prod --base-href=/route1/ --deploy-url=/route1/
```

if you need deploy into different root context , change the value of the parameters and build it again.

**But if you don't know the deploy root context**, the plan B is:

Change `useHash` to `true` in the `app-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [/* your routes goes here */];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            useHash: true, // change useHash to true
            enableTracing: !environment.production
        })
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and change the `base href` in `index.html` to `./`,

```
<head>
  <base href="./">
</head>
```

**don't** add `base-href` and `deploy-url` parameter with `ng build`, then you can deploy your app to any web root.  but the the url will be end with `/{webroot}/#/{client-route}`

Comment: Hi zhimin. Thanks for the answer, but as this would be deployed in multiple different location as described in the question, one build each customer is not really "smooth", right?

Comment: no, it's not comtomer smooth. another way is use set `useHash` to true in the app-routing.module.ts , and change the basehref in index.html to `./`,  don't add base-href and deploy-url parameter with ng build, then you can deploy your app to any web root. but the the url will be end with `/{webroot}/index.html#/{client-route}`

Answer (score 4):

I believe either defining `"baseHref"` option in angular.json or `base` tag in your `head` in index.html should help.

Answer (score 1):

### This is what you want

In your angular.json file where is your project name, find your project name there is a property **architect**

so in the architect.build.assets:['add the path of your assets you want to bundle']

#### example

```
"app1": {
      "root": "projects/app1/",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/app1/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/app1",
            "index": "projects/app1/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/app1/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/app1/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/app1/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "projects/app1/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/app1/src/assets",
              "../more-assets-folder" <=== add your assets here
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/app1/src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
```

Comment: Thanks @George C
The asset is already copied to build output by setting the assets config in angular.json
They just not correctly referenced if I would give my application to multiple teams, hosted in multiple places...

Comment: @qkhanhpro if I helped you, please consider to upvote my answer I would like to help you again. good luck

Answer (score 0):

There is a flag called --deploy-url which can be used with the ng build command. The deploy-url is the URL where files or assets will be stored. If deploy-url is their then the angular app will open the assets and files from this url other wise it used the app url or base-url.

Try the build command

```
ng build --prod --base-href domainname.com/app/app1/ --deploy-url domainname.com/app/app1/script/
```

For more details follow the links

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6666
- https://shekhargulati.com/2017/07/06/angular-4-use-of-base-href-and-deploy-url-build-options/